# How to run a command on Macbook startup?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

I'm running the latest Sierra version, and every time I reboot I need to execute

```
mysql.server start
```

I'd like to simply add this command to a startup script, but I've spent an hour looking at setting up daemons, etc, but I feel like it shouldn't be that difficult.

Is there an easy way to put this in some sort of startup script so every time I start my macbook it's run in the background?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it to happen when you log in, put it in your user account's Login Items (System Preferences > Users & Groups > [Your Account] > Login Items).

If you want it to happen on every boot, regardless of whether or not anyone logs in (and regardless of who logs in), then create a launchd plist file for it and put said plist in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`. See the man page for `launchd.plist(5)`, or other online tutorials and tools for creating launchd jobs.

Comment: thanks for the response, the Login Items sounds like an easy thing, I added a .sh script but it doesn't seem to run when I login, any ideas?

Comment: @MarkKadlec A few ideas: Make sure you've `chmod`ed the script to be executable. Try renaming the `myscript.sh` to `myscript.command`. Make sure it opens up Terminal and runs when you double-click it from the Finder.

Comment: Changing to .command seems to have fixed this!